# Mysql restrict on delete check

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database with restrict on delete setting.
I have this delete query:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete_id']))
{
    $sqldelete="DELETE FROM tblAcqDetail WHERE ID=".$_POST['delete_id'];
    $resultdelete = $conn->query($sqldelete);
}
```

How can I check if the query does delete anything or is restricted by mysql.

I need to run an update query (see below) only if the delete query works.
I tried:

```
if ($resultdelete->affected_rows> 0)  {
    // Escape user inputs for security
    $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['status']);
    if(isset($_POST['status']))
    {
        $setsql="UPDATE tblInvoiceDetail SET TRANSFER = '0' WHERE ID='$status'";
        $setresult = $conn->query($setsql);
    }
}
```

I also tried

```
if ($resultdelete->num_rows > 0)  {
```

And also :

```
if ($resultdelete)  {
```

All of the above stop the update query from executing.

Comment: **A:** `mysqli_affected_rows()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: You're using it wrong `if ($resultdelete->affected_rows> 0)` RTM ^

Comment: Many including myself have posted an answer. You can pick any which one to close the question. *The choice is yours*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

From the docs:

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.

Note this is run on the connection object, not the result. So use `$conn->affected_rows` instead of `$resultdelete->affected_rows`.

Comment: I don't understand how to use it I thought `if ($resultdelete->affected_rows> 0)` is the way

Comment: Note you are calling it on the *result*, not the connection object as required.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than passing `$resultdelete` in to `mysqli_affected_rows` you actually want to pass the DB link (returned by mysqli_connect) which will give you the number of rows affected by the previous query

```
 $sqldelete="DELETE FROM tblAcqDetail WHERE ID=".$_POST['delete_id'];
 $resultdelete = $conn->query($sqldelete);

if ($conn->affected_rows > 0)  {// pass db link here
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're referencing the wrong thing

```
if ($resultdelete->affected_rows> 0)  {
```

But

```
$resultdelete = $conn->query($sqldelete);
```

only [returns a boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)(emphasis mine).

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. **For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE**

You want to reference the connection itself for how many rows were affected

```
if ($conn->affected_rows> 0)  {
```

Answer (score 1):

If condition should be

```
  if ($conn->affected_rows> 0){}
```

not

```
  if ($resultdelete->affected_rows> 0){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using it wrong `if ($resultdelete->affected_rows> 0)`  you're using [`num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) syntax with the `>0` bit.

- The connection is passed to the function and not from the result set.

RTM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Object oriented style
`int $mysqli->affected_rows;`

Procedural style
`int mysqli_affected_rows ( mysqli $link )`

From the manual:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Insert rows */
$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE Language SELECT * from CountryLanguage");
printf("Affected rows (INSERT): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);

$mysqli->query("ALTER TABLE Language ADD Status int default 0");

/* update rows */
$mysqli->query("UPDATE Language SET Status=1 WHERE Percentage > 50");
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);

/* delete rows */
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM Language WHERE Percentage < 50");
printf("Affected rows (DELETE): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);

/* select all rows */
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT CountryCode FROM Language");
printf("Affected rows (SELECT): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);

$result->close();

/* Delete table Language */
$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE Language");

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>

Procedural style
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if (!$link) {
    printf("Can't connect to localhost. Error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Insert rows */
mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE Language SELECT * from CountryLanguage");
printf("Affected rows (INSERT): %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));

mysqli_query($link, "ALTER TABLE Language ADD Status int default 0");

/* update rows */
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE Language SET Status=1 WHERE Percentage > 50");
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));

/* delete rows */
mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM Language WHERE Percentage < 50");
printf("Affected rows (DELETE): %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));

/* select all rows */
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT CountryCode FROM Language");
printf("Affected rows (SELECT): %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));

mysqli_free_result($result);

/* Delete table Language */
mysqli_query($link, "DROP TABLE Language");

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```